# Wordpress theme "Twenty Fifteen" background

Tags: css, wordpress, background

I'm using the Wordpress "Twenty Fifteen" theme for a website.

I'd like to change the background color left of the sidebar, but I don't find how. 
I can change the background of the body, page, sidebar, etc., but not of the area left of the sidebar (which has the same colour).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Community likes when you show what you've done so far. Show us your examples, and the community will surely help. Any code snippets would be highly appreciated.

Comment: screenshot please..

Comment: Do you want something like this ??? https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxZYq.jpg

Comment: Yes, indeed, the yellow part.

Comment: ok proving you the answer.. Also you need to write some custom css for this.

Comment: Do check the answer .. happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1- Go to the admin of your theme. Appearance > Customize as shown in screeshot.**[image]

**Step 2- GO to Additional Css tab-**

[image]

**Step 3-Add css in this tab as below. Give your own colors as you want.**

```
body:before{     background-color: yellow;}/* Css for left part only*/
.sidebar{background-color: blue;}/* Css for the sidebar*/
```

[image]

> **Note:** You have to specify both colors for both left part only and sidebar here only then only it will work properly.

Comment: I absolutely did not notice that there's a :before. :-) Thanks!